# Unable to deploy solution with List Templates in Module

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-list, visual-studio-2015

I've couple of custom List Templates in a module, and I want to create this lists if they don't exist. But when I try to deploy the solution I got an error:

> ExceptionMessage: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070970

My Module Element.xml looks like:

```
<Module Name="Lists" Url="_catalogs/lt" Path="Lists">
<File Path="GNPages" Url="GNPages" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists ="TRUE"></File>
<File Path="GNTiles" Url="GNTiles" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists ="TRUE"></File>
<File Path="GNTilesToolBox" Url="GNTilesToolBox" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists ="TRUE"></File>
<File Path="GNSettings" Url="GNSettings" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists ="TRUE"></File>
```

I've all my list in a folder and not in a Module, but then each time I deploy my App it deleted the existing lists and recreated at it each time, and I want to just create lists if they don't exist, and that's why I put them in to a Module, but I'm not able to deploy my solution....

Answer (score 0):

If you re-deploy your app, it will create your lists new each time. Because every time when you deploy your app, it will retract your app completely, If you noticed your url then every time when you deploy your app, url will be changed. As app- model works as separate site then our site-collection/our farm.

You will get more info from below reference links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590089/Apps-in-SharePoint
- http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/08/create-lists-content-types-files-etc.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142379.aspx